# Flexbox going outside its container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a header bar in which there are 3 elements, the first one takes up as much space as it can, while the other 2 take up as much as they need.

```
| title | button | button |
```

The problem happens when the title part is too wide. The content of it does not wrap and it just pushes the buttons off the screen.

Let me demonstrate with a codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqrpVg

**Update**

I see it working now, but can anyone explain what the values do to achieve what I want, instead of just telling me the solution, so I can understand it.

Comment: I think you over-complicated things. Here's a simplified version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMoJzd?editors=1100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that you're setting the buttons to shrink, while explicitly telling the title not to shrink. That means that the title will grab all of the space. Now, if you set `flex: 1;` on the title and remove `flex: 0 1 auto;` and `flex-basis: content;` from the buttons, it works as expected: the buttons are always shown and the content of the title is wrapped.

See [the modified codepen](https://codepen.io/andreiv/pen/gmxrvL?editors=1100).

When you're setting `flex: 1 0 auto;` you're enabling the growth (`1`) of a flex item and disabling its shrinking (`0`). So the browser will never shrink the title element in order to make room for the buttons.

When using `flex: 0 1 auto;` you're telling the browser that the flex item is not really important and, when there's not enough room, the flex item should shrink to make room for other elements.

Here's what my solution does:

- it sets `flex: 1;` on the title, which tells the browser that the element can expand and can shrink; it also instructs to grab as much available space as possible;
- the default values for the `flex` shorthand are `0 1 auto`, which is not really needed;
- finally, `flex-basis: content` is not really supported; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 6):

I have created this Codepen for you:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWyXQd

**Code added:**

```
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
```

I'm not sure that this exactly what you want but that is what I gathered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all properties from buttons. Just use display:flex on the container. That's it.

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: flex;

}

.title {
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-right: 1rem;}

.button {
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin-right: 1rem;}
```

https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/PpKNBm

Comment: I don't want the buttons to wrap to a new row, I want them to be on the right

Comment: I have removed every flex property except display:flex on the contianer. You need the basic implementation with all default values.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-2 mx-auto">
    <div class="p-3 bg-white rounded-4">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3 py-3">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-1 align-items-start text-light-gray overflow-hidden">
                <div class="fw-bold lh-1 w-100 text-truncate">Brand Name Private Limited A very Long Name</div>
                <div class="lh-1 fw-medium">Network Type</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Visit https://codepen.io/kushagra99/pen/poQmBoZ for a working Example!

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to explain why this resolves the asker's question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).